# Select row with middle value in a column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to find the value that is in the middle of the column `Quantity`.

```
  Branch Buyer  Quantity                Date
0      A  Carl         1 2013-01-01 13:00:00
1      A  Mark         4 2013-01-01 13:05:00
2      A  Carl         5 2013-10-01 20:00:00
3      A  Carl         1 2013-10-02 10:00:00
4      A   Joe         8 2013-10-01 20:00:00
5      A   Joe         1 2013-10-02 10:00:00
6      A   Joe         9 2013-12-02 12:00:00
7      B  Carl         7 2013-12-02 14:00:00
```

`np.median([1,4,5,1,8,1,9,7])` returns, `4.5`, but it's not an actual value in the column.

After sorting:

```
[1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

How can I get the row with `4` or `5` for `Quantity`?

Comment: Please post the dataframe's generator.

Comment: @AnnZen, it should be fine. You don't need the dataframe to reproduce the issue. The list is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]

a[np.argmin(abs(a - np.median(a)))]

# Output: 4.0
```

Explanation:

1. find the median using `np.median()`
2. find the distance between each number and the median using `abs()`
3. find the index of the number having the minimum distance
4. get the value from the original list using the index

If there are multiple numbers having equal distance (4 and 5 in your example), whichever comes first will be picked.

Answer (score 1):

For a even entries in a list, my understanding is median is an average of middle two entires. For odd entries median is the middle entry.

for an even number of rows and **sorted data** you could try either:

```
if df.shape[0] is even (add appropriate code):
  np.median(dataFrame.Quantity[:-1])
  or
  np.median(dataFrame.Quantity[1:])
```

Comment: I don't think this is a feasible solution. It only works for this particular example. If the number of values is odd, your code will actually create the problem rather than solving it.

Comment: Christopher,  I agree! it needs a logic to check odd entries before. you could use dataFrame.shape to get row and column could, which is trivial computation operation

Answer (score 1):

To get the middle value of Quantity column you can try out this:

```
x=len(df['Quantity'])
df['Quantity'][(0+x)//2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an index that is closest to the middle of the list:

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
print(lst[len(lst)//2])
```

Output:

```
5
```

As you can see, `len(lst)` results in `8`, so `len(lst)//2` gives `4`. The value for the fourth index of `lst` is `5`.